# Does Hodor say anything apart from "Hodor" in the books?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I haven't read the books and I don't even know if he is a character in the books, I assume he is, so I'm curious to know if he says anything apart form that one word? He only seems to say that in the TV version.

Comment: Hodor Hodor Hodor.

Comment: @Simon - http://i.imgur.com/iM1LYqe.jpg

Comment: @Richard One does not simply walk into Hodor.

Comment: You'd think it'd get old, but there's a couple of dramatic parts in the books where a simple unexpected "Hodor!" makes for some solid comedy.

Comment: "NOW TELL US WHO YOU ARE!" "Hodor!"

Comment: I *really* wanted to create a new account with the username "Hodor", a multi-paragraph 'About Me' full of the word "Hodor," and then post an answer below consisting entirely of punctuation and "Hodor".  We really need to implement 20% Trolling time here so good ideas like this one aren't squandered in the future.

Comment: @Jaydles Hodor...

Comment: http://www.teampwnicorn.com/portfolio/game-of-thrones-dating-profiles-hodor/

Comment: George RR Martin himself has you all beaten to the punch! Plus what I would consider an authoritative answer to the question: https://twitter.com/_GRRM_/status/456824016641486848

Comment: Now I think of it, Hodor's dialogue has some resemblance to both the Librarian and the Death of Rats in Discworld: "Hodor, hodor hodor." "Oook, oook! Oook oook." SQUEAK.

Comment: @coburne It never gets old *in the books*. The internet is a different story…

Comment: @etheranger: That's not GRRM's twitter account. He's only recently joined Twitter: https://twitter.com/GRRMspeaking

Comment: Reading about Hodor makes me want to read the books, just for the sections with Hodor in them...except I'm almost positive, based on what I've heard, that Hodor will die.

Comment: Hold the door!!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No, in the books this is the only word he says. Interestingly, Old Nan [points out](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hodor#Appearance_and_personality) that Hodor is not even his real name:

> Theon Greyjoy had once commented that Hodor did not know much, but no one could doubt that he knew his name. Old Nan had cackled like a hen when Bran told her that, and confessed that Hodor’s real name was Walder. No one knew where ‘Hodor’ had come from, she said, but when he started saying it, they started calling him by it. It was the only word he had.

Comment: That's very interesting.  +1

Comment: @Mkalafut - His real name is Walder, which has lead to a crazy theory that he's an unknown Walder Frey bastard.

Comment: @SystemDown It's pretty clear that Walder Frey is a GoT style hulk, who turns into Hodor when he gets angry. HODOR SMASH.

Comment: Could "*Hodor*" actually be a mispronouncement of his name "*Walder*"?

Comment: @TheMathemagician That's exactly what I thought after seeing his real name in the link in Justin Ethier's answer. He may have pronounced it like that as a child and continued to do so as he got older, but still childlike as an adult.

Comment: @TheMathemagician - Never thought about that before, but I think you're on to something :)

Comment: @JustinEthier Maybe Old Nan in her (possible) dotage has got it wrong and his name really is Hodor and is getting it mixed up with Walder Frey.

Comment: Also interesting is that Old Nan is his great-grandmother. I think fans should demand an Old Nan/Hodor family tree from GRRM.

Comment: @camden_kid - I don't know, she seemed pretty sharp for someone her age...

Comment: @JustinEthier - Except when it comes to remembering which Brandon Stark she actually nursed. My own tin-foil theory is that she's an immortal child of the forest who nursed Bran the Builder and passed down he warging magic to the Stark bloodline through her milk. Note, we never see her die when Winterfell falls! Dun dun dunnnn!

Comment: If "Hodor" only says "Hodor", how did Old Nan learn his real name?

Comment: @MarkRogers - She is Hodor's great-grandmother...

Comment: @SystemDown I believe she is the young girl from Bran's visions who's standing on her toes to kiss a very tall Knight in winterfell. That tall knight may have been Ser Duncan the Tall which makes his genes responsible for Hodor's height.

Answer (score 11):

Nope.

> Even when Bran possesses his body to fight the wrights outside of the three-eyed crow's cave. He screams with rage as he fights with Hodor's body and something like "HODOR HODOR HODORRRRR!!" is what comes out. Bran doesn't want them to know of this ability so he doesn't attempt to talk outside of a "Hodor" here and there to convince the others that nothing is amiss. I suspect that even if he did though he wouldn't be able to, much like trying to speak as a wolf.

Answer (score 4):

## No

He has only ever said Hodor in the books and Bran even comments on this at least once.

> Yet now that the last day was at hand, suddenly Bran felt lost. Winterfell had been the only home he had ever known. His father had told him that he ought to say his farewells today, and he had tried. After the hunt had ridden out, he wandered through the castle with his wolf at his side, intending to visit the ones who would be left behind, Old Nan and Gage the cook, Mikken in his smithy, **Hodor the stableboy who smiled so much and took care of his pony and never said anything but "Hodor,"** the man in the glass gardens who gave him a blackberry when he came to visit …
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Bran II</sub>

Apparently he does hum at least once too, though not another word it is another sound he can make.

> They left Old Nan in the tower room with her needles and her memories. **Hodor hummed tunelessly** as he carried Bran down the steps and through the gallery, with Maester Luwin following behind, hurrying to keep up with the stableboy's long strides.
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Bran IV</sub>

Though he wasn't always called Hodor, but once Walder, or Wylis in the show.

> Hodor lifted Bran as easy as if he were a bale of hay, and cradled him against his massive chest. He always smelled faintly of horses, but it was not a bad smell. His arms were thick with muscle and matted with brown hair. "Hodor," he said again. Theon Greyjoy had once commented that Hodor did not know much, but no one could doubt that he knew his name. Old Nan had cackled like a hen when Bran told her that, and confessed that **Hodor's real name was Walder.** No one knew where "Hodor" had come from, she said, but** when he started saying it, they started calling him by it. It was the only word he had.**
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Bran IV</sub>

In the show it has been revealed how Hodor got his name, via seeing his future self holding a door whilst being clawed by wights as Meera Reed told him to "Hold the Door" repeatedly.

The meaning behind the name is the [same as the books](http://uk.businessinsider.com/hodor-hold-the-door-in-books-2016-5?r=US&IR=T) but apparently it will come about in a different context. Though the quote is from reddit I've read the same thing before from "something official" but can't find it now.

> Someone asked him about the show's Hodor name reveal. He said that his name reveal in the books will differ in the context and how it happens. So while the name will still mean the same thing (Hold the Door), it will be very different from the show's reveal. He said he came up with the name idea in 1991 and seemed depressed that the show got to reveal it before he did.
>   <sub>[r/asoiaf, Got to hear GRRM's thoughts on a name reveal tonight](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/4kruq7/spoilers_everything_got_to_hear_grrms_thoughts_on/)</sub>

As such we can speculate he said more than just Hodor before his life changing event and he's probably also said "Hold the Door" a few times, but again this is all before he became known as Hodor.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

Hodor's name was Wylis (or Walder in the books) when he was young and he could talk like most people ([Home](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Home), season 6, episode 2). But since a traumatic event his only word is "Hodor", as shown in [The Door](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Door) (season 6, episode 5).

Comment: This is true, although this happened in the show so technically in the books he has still only said "Hodor". Hopefully we get to see this event when TWOW is released...

Comment: Also technically he wasn't Hodor then but still a good answer

Answer (score -2):

I truly think I have the discovered the "real" reason and it simply has to do with the character that he is base upon "Loial" from the Wheel of Time series.  There comes a time in the series where Loial tells "Perrin"  that he will guard a door with his life if need be beyond which "Faile" lies unconscious.  Perrin is the character who Bran is based upon and Faile is the character who Meera is based upon.  Loial is an Ogier who is a giant compared to men.  Perrin has a strong attraction to Faile at this point in the story the same as Bran towards Meera.  The differences.  Where Loial is a bookworm and very intelligent; Hodor appears to be a simpleton on the surface.  Faile lies unconscious in TWOT where it will be Bran in ASOIAF.  If you substitute "Guard the Door" for "Hold the Door" you get "HODOR".  Bran wargs Hodor to Hold the door to protect Meera and that is his only thought.  Bran's only thought at that Moment to protect the girl that he loves gets transported back in time to the young Hodor due to Bran's ability to time jump and sort of leaves the seemly intelligent Hodor with a form of PTSD allowing him to only say the words "HODOR" from that moment on.

https://howthegameofthronesends.blogspot.com/2016/05/hodor-is-loial.html

http://howthegameofthronesends.blogspot.com/2016/02/bran-cave-and-children-of-forest.html

Comment: Welcome to SFF. While this may make an interesting theory, we are looking for answers that can be supported by the works. Take the tour to see what kind of answers we are looking for.

Comment: It is now revealed in Season 6 of the show, that his name was Wylis. And he talked. We will see what happens to him maybe in this season or next, perhaps.